# InterBase - Casting calculated column as varying character

Tags: sql, interbase

I am attempting to write a query that uses a calculated value, I then want to cast this calculated value as a string so that I can add a '%' to the end.

However I am not succeeding with the query below:

```
select 
    a.Subjects, a.RequiredTime, b.HRS,
    CAST(((b.HRS / a.RequiredTime)*100) as VARCHAR) as PercentageComplete
from 
    Subjects a 
inner join 
    V_SUMMARYHOURSSUBJECT b on a.Subjects = b.Subject
```

This is the error that the query generates:

> Error at line 1 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown
>   - line 2, char 46 ) SQL

Comment: Please add the error you get, or *how* the query performs differently from what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to convert from integer/numeric/double to a string using InterBase SQL; a string length must be specified as part of the `CAST` function for example

```
select a.Subjects, a.RequiredTime, b.HRS,
CAST(((b.HRS / a.RequiredTime)*100) as VARCHAR(10)) as PercentageComplete
from Subjects a inner join V_SUMMARYHOURSSUBJECT b
on a.Subjects = b.Subject
```